# Android drawaable configuration qualifiers for different screen and densitites

Tags: android, android-layout

HI i have a confusion regarding screen size and its density 
lets suppose I have smalll screen , normal , larage and xlarge screen
and all the screen have different densily low , medium , high and xhigh
so how i ll manage the drawabl folder for small , normal , large and extra
large screen for there different densities

drawable-samll-ldpi

drawable-samll-mdpi

drawable-samll-hdpi

---

drawable-normal-ldpi

drawable-normal-mdpi

drawable-normal-hdpi

---

drawable-large-ldpi

drawable-large-mdpi

drawable-large-hdpi

or there is only 3 folder for all screen size for their different densities like

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-hdpi

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

show this recomendation http://luckesky.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/auto-ajustar-tamano-de-aplicaciones-al.html
so you can see size screen more sold

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a link from the Android Developer site :
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

These are the official documentation section I'd suggest you to read:

1 - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (general theory)

2 - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html (training with examples)

3 - http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html (training with examples)

4 - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html (general theory)